# Charset for foreign languages

Tags: html, xhtml, character-encoding

I'm currently doing some HTML that with urdu, farsi and chinese simplified characters. I'm having problems finding good resources online on what charset to use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=???" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

UTF-8 can encode any character in any language in the Unicode standard, is ASCII-compatible and is well-supported these days. There's little reason not to use it for everything.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using UTF-8, that can encode any Unicode character.

But apart from declaring the encoding in the document itself, it’s more important that your code is actually encoded in UTF-8. So get yourself a editor that can handle this encoding properly and declare the encoding in the HTTP header as it has a [higher priority](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#spec-char-encoding).

Answer (score 4):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)